# How do I know where to look for bounty hunting/bail bond missions?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

So, playing as Trevor, there is this woman, Maude. She offers bail bond missions.
However, I am stuck right from the beginning.

How do I figure out where to look for the people I'm supposed to go get?

I must have not paid attention when I talked to her, and there's no indicator on my map. I also can't seem to go back and read our dialog, to check if she mentioned an area to look in.

Comment: I highly recommend using Google for that. Maude sends you mails with pictures showing the locations of the targets, but they're not terribly helpful, especially when the target is hiding in a place you haven't uncovered yet on your map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking to her I received an EMail which told me where to look for the first guy.

Minor Spoiler:

> The first person is supposed to be in a quarry of some sort. I have not found him yet, so I can not provide any more details.

Comment: If you don't get the email, or the email disappears then check out this [question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/138144/did-not-receive-maudes-message-to-start-bail-bond-missions)

Answer (score 4):

I think that's part of the challenge, recognising the places in the description/picture and working it out from that. There's no indicator on the map to tell you where they are. As @Nicolas mentions, one is located in a q------, which is fairly easy to find if you've explored some of the map / look at the paper map in your game box. The second is almost impossible, third for me was very easy as I'd been there before.

It's one of those things, when you know the answer, looking back at the picture you start to see things which give it away (a special building, the shape of a road, etc) so it's just a case of keep hunting.

One thing I'd say, use the paper map to look up road shapes and the like rather than the in-game map, for the second one I hadn't discovered the area yet on the in-game map so I would never have found it.

Oh, a last thought, if you get the GTA manual (PC install or app I think) it has a very detailed, Google Maps type zoom thing (with aerial view) which you can use to match up like for like what you can see in the picture. If you're really stuck but don't what to cheat I'd suggest trying that.

Comment: Comparing the image in Maude's mail vs. the paper map usually does the deal for me. The road layout is unique and visible on the big map.

Comment: Searching by helicopter also makes it easier, as all the pictures are taken from up high.