# Did Not Receive Maude's message to start Bail Bond missions?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm using Trevor & do not receive Maude's texts or emails to start Bail Bond missions, even I have completed the main story, as well as Mrs. Philips' storyline.

I have completed Special Bonds mission as well. What will trigger the 1st mission ?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't receive it? Bond missions don't appear on the map, you've got to go to the correct place yourself.

Comment: She was a strangers and freaks mission, I believe, and then the emails just keep coming after that.

Comment: Double check Trevor's mailbox. No Maude. what if I accidentally delete the email ? not sure if I did so or not.

Comment: *sidnote:* Even the email is deleted / purged after too many emails, the mission still continues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the mission "Mr Philips" with Trevor, you should see an orange question mark appear near Sandy Shores - this is the Special Bonds mission where you meet Maude.
About 5 minutes after this she sends you an email with a map of the location of Ralph Ostrowski, the first of the "Bail Bonds" missions.

Now, I did this first mission successfully, and then she sent me another email for the 2nd Bail Bond mission, but it has since disappeared! Same problemo I think. I had to google for Larry Tupper's whereabouts, and sure enough he was there, even without the email.

As long as you've met Maude already, I think you are going to have to google for the whereabouts of Ralph and I'm sure he will be waiting for you there, even though the email has disappeared/or you never received it.

Just in case you are wondering, Ralph is located at:

> At the bottom of Davis Quartz Quarry (southeast of Sandy Shores, other side of Senora Freeway)

Comment: Yes. I found the Quarry guy at last. Additional finding: he is NOT always there. I found him at night, but not found in the morning.